# Spring Batch custom ItemReader won't open

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch project where I have `JsonResouurceAsyncPagingItemReader`, a custom `ItemReader` which asynchronously retrieves data from a web service.

This custom `ItemReader` uses a `ExecutorService` to submit calls to the web service. However I am having trouble to initialize it.

I tried to initialize it through the `doOpen` method provided by `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader`, however seems `doOpen` it's not being called.

The `ItemReader` is being injected by Spring in this way:

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public ItemReader<Map<String, Object>> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['lastRun']}") Date lastRun,
        @Value("#{jobParameters['codInt']}") Long codInt) {

    Map<String, Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if (lastRun != null) {
        parameterValues.put("lastRun", DateFormatUtils.format(lastRun, dateFormat));
    }
    if (codInt != null) {
        parameterValues.put("codInt", codInt);
    }

    JsonResourceAsyncPagingItemReader<Map<String, Object>> reader = new JsonResourceAsyncPagingItemReader<>();
    reader.setHttpUrl(server + pathTemplate);
    reader.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
    reader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);
    reader.setPageSize(pageSize);

    return reader;
}
```

And further used in a `Step` like this:

```
@Bean
public Step importProductStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("importProductJobStep")
            .<Map<String, Object>, Product>chunk(1000)
            .reader(reader(null, null))
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}
```

Any idea on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you return an ItemStream, or an ItemStreamWriter, it would should fine.
([Look at this ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2097))

Comment: Thanks, you nailed the problem !! I changed the return type from ItemReader to ItemStreamReader and it worked perfect.